# Excel pivot % Running Total

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table

It seems, that when you use cumulative running total in percent for each month/quarter in a year, excel divides by the total number for a whole year.

[image]

Am I doing it wrong, or it's a microsoft's bug?

Comment: If you are not showing how you are doing it, how would we know if it is wrong?

Comment: So build the calculation for each month using only the entries for that month. sumifs(), then you can do a summation of those 12 values or do a sumifs for entries for that year. You need to build calculations that reflect what you want, NOT what any Pivot tool guesses for you.

Comment: yeah, I know how to do it manually, but with pivot table, it seems that logic isn't correct (or correct, depends what you want)